# Changing a css style of the active element in angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and am looking for a technique to rotate a piece when the user is dragging it by pressing the 'r' key. My initial idea is to swap the *flex-direction: column* to *flex-direction: row* of the "item" css class

```
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* alternate between row & column*/  
   margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

My questions is, is this possible? 
My other idea is to have to classes item-column and item-row and swap them but even doing that I don't know how to access the element in the `item.component.ts`.
I know that with the .item:active selector I can reach the element, but don't know how to do it from the controller.
Here is the code I have so far: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-drag-and-keypress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use drag event :

```
<div draggable="true" (dragstart)="onDragStart($event)" (dragend)="onDragEnd($event)" class="item">
  <div class="piece" *ngFor="let p of [].constructor(itemSize); let i = index">i</div>  
</div>
```

Then in your ts, hold the active element in a varible so the `keyup` event can recognize which element is active :

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() itemSize: number;
  draggingElement : Element;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.itemSize) {
      throw new TypeError("'itemSize' is required");
    }    
  }

  onDragStart(e){
    this.draggingElement = e.target
  }

  onDragEnd(e){
    this.draggingElement = null;
  }

  @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  keyEventUp(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
    if(event.key.toLowerCase() === "r") {     
      if(this.draggingElement) {
         console.log(this.draggingElement);
      }    
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: I don't intend to add an "active" class to the div. The angular cdk sets the "item class" as active, I know that because I styled it like .item:active {...}. What I want is to know in the keyEventDown function to know when the :active is present in order to distinguish each item is being dragged.

Comment: It works but I quit this approach. It looks like while dragging the 'key' event is a bit delayed and also on mobile it will be hard to do such thing. I would rather user a double click to rotate it. Appreciate your help